# set scheduler in express app based on a request, and clear it before set time if required

Tags: node.js, express, settimeout

I have a page where we play live stream videos. Once the video is started, we are capturing the time and after 1 hr. we want to fire a socket event which will hide the video for guest users, while logged in users can continue watching.

All is set except the fact that how to call clearTimeOut to clear the setTimeOut object which was set when video was started.

When livestream starts

```
setTimeoutIds[val] =  setTimeout(function() {
    req.app.io.emit('disable_for_guest',req.body);
    live_events.update({event_id:req.body.eventId},{guest_visibility:false},function(err,data){
        //All ok
    });

}, disable_after_milliseconds);
```

When Livestream ends

```
live_events.update({event_id:req.body.eventId}, 
{guest_visibility:true},function(err,data){

if (req.body.eventId in setTimeoutIds){
    var event_id = req.body.eventId;
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutIds.event_id);
    delete setTimeoutIds.event_id;
} else {
    console.log('Event not found'+req.body.eventId);
}

req.app.io.emit('event_ended',req.body);
```

Please suggest experts!

Thanks

Comment: please post `code` instead of screenshots.

Comment: @MukeshSharma Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the `Timeout` object returned by `setTimeout` in `setTimeoutIds[val]`. I assume that `val` is `req.body.eventId`.

So if `req.body.eventId` is `abc` for example, `setTimeoutIds` looks now like this:

```
{'abc': <Timeout object>}
```

You then try to access the property `event_id`:

```
clearTimeout(setTimeoutIds.event_id);
delete setTimeoutIds.event_id;
```

What you want to do instead is to access the property with the *name stored in* `event_id`.

```
clearTimeout(setTimeoutIds[event_id]);
delete setTimeoutIds[event_id];
```

Make sure that `event_id` is really equal. `req.body.eventId` might be a string, while you initially worked with an integer.

Comment: var setTimeoutIds              = {};    This is how it is declared, does associate array syntax works in JS, I doubt.

Comment: Thanks, but you use Object notation in example, while you pointed array syntax on answer. I am already using object notation but its not working. I doubt, when request comes back to the same code, it doesn't know setTimeOut variable anymore, do you think this could be the case?

Comment: I've expanded my answer, hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, apparently `setTimeoutIds` becomes empty. That seems unrelated to this question, so I would suggest asking a new question (unless you can figure it out yourself, of course).

Comment: Ok, I have created new thread for this at https://stackoverflow.com/q/51301332/9303776