# node process can not find setTimeout object in subsequent requests

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, settimeout

I am trying to clear timeout set using setTimeout method by node process, in subsequent requests (using express). So, basically, I set timeout when our live stream event starts (get notified by webhook) and aim to stop this for guest users after one hour. One hour is being calculated via setTimeout, which works fine so far. However, if event gets stopped before one hour, I need to clear the timeout. I am trying to use clearTimeOut but it just can't find same variable.

```
// Event starts
var setTimeoutIds              = {};    
  var val  = req.body.eventId;
  setTimeoutIds[val] =  setTimeout(function() {

        req.app.io.emit('disable_for_guest',req.body);                                
        live_events.update({event_id:req.body.eventId},{guest_visibility:false},function(err,data){
                                            //All ok
         });
     }, disable_after_milliseconds);
     console.log(setTimeoutIds);                                        
     req.app.io.emit('session_started',req.body);

When event ends:
 try{
           var event_id = req.body.eventId;
           clearTimeout(setTimeoutIds[event_id]);
           delete setTimeoutIds[event_id];
      }catch(e){
           console.log('Event ID could not be removed' + e);
      }
 req.app.io.emit('event_ended',req.body);
```

Output :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4beJV.png)

Comment: It seems you're doing everything right, but does the event ends part have access to the setTimeoutIds variable? Your posted code is too abbreviated. Does the error message from the catch block appear in your log?

Comment: It does have access to the variable, but I feel like it is not pointing to the original variable reference, it tries to initialize new one. So, I get empty object when trying to remove, see this plz : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4beJV.png . JFYI, var setTimeoutIds              = {};  is declared right above everything, so scope does not seem to be the issue, its just Node does not remember the reference.

Comment: As @Sonata said, the excerpt you posted is not enough to diagnose the issue. Post the complete file, or at least enough so the structure of your code is visible.

Comment: @Sonata Please refer to this http://collabedit.com/7vc7r for full method code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `setTimeoutIds` in the scope of the handler. You must define it at module level.

```
var setTimeoutIds = {};    

router.post('/webhook', function(req, res) {
     ...
```

That makes the variable available until the next restart of the server.

**Note:** this approach only works as long as you only have a single server with a single node process serving your application. Once you go multi-process and/or multi-server, you need a completely different approach.

Comment: Right at spot! Thanks. It worked. Yes, I am moving to storing socket data to Redis adapter for scalability, do you think that will be fine for storing timeOut object as well (in Redis)?

Comment: No, storing the timeout object in Redis won't work. Here is one possible solution: instead of storing the timeout to cancel it later, you could store a key in Redis. The callback of the timeout checks if the key exists before doing anything. To cancel the timeout, you don't call clearTimeout, you just remove the key from Redis.

Comment: Sounds brilliant! That will save hassle completely. Thank you very much @Daniel for your help, you have been awesome!